# Add color to custom ls alias

Tags: terminal, bash, color, alias

I created an alias to display permissions in octet format:

```
alias lso="ls -l | awk '
{
  k=0;
  for (i=0;i<=8;i++)
    k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i));
  if (k)
    printf("%0o ",k);
  print
}'
```

I also set added this code to display ls in a colored format:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
```

What I am wondering, is how to make my alias display in a colored format as well?
Also, if anyone could explain the syntax of the alias (after the pipe)? I copied the text and am trying to learn to be able to synthesize commands like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `ls` provided with OSX comes from BSD and won't allow you to do what you want.

Using [CoreUtils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) ls (installed with macport it's available with the `gls` command)

You'll get your colors using `--color=always`:

```
ls -l --color=always | awk '
{
  k=0;
  for (i=0;i<=8;i++)
    k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i));
  if (k)
    printf("%0o ",k);
  print
}'
```

---

About the awk part :

- `ls` outputs file permissions as 9 characters. That's why there's a loop.
- the `substr` returns at each step one of the char (incremented index, 1 char-length substring)
- `~/[rwx]` converts the char to 1 if it's a `r` or a `w` or a `x`
- the operation behind just does the operation the get the decimal result
- `print("%0o ", k)` just prints the octal result of the decimal value calculated before